# Perform background PHP task using TideSDK

Tags: php, javascript, curl, tidesdk

Is it possible to run PHP code in the background using TideSDK? I am trying to upload a file using curl in PHP. The GUI becomes unresponsive during the upload whether Javascript calls PHP immediately in response to an event or whether the event is used to schedule the call.

Javascript calls PHP directly from handler:

```
upload_file(path_to_file)
```

Javascript schedules call to PHP directly from handler:

```
setTimeout(function() {upload_file(path_to_file);}, 250);
```

The file upload is done using the PHP curl function. I've tried both `curl_exec()` and `curl_multi_exec()`. `curl_multi_exec()` seems promising but the example code spins calling `curl_multi_exec()` repeatedly.

I'm considering breaking this loop up to return back to JS between loops to attempt to help the problem.

Comment: How does Javascript call PHP "directly"? If you're doing it asynchronously, it should already be done in the background.

Comment: I'm calling PHP from Javascript following the TideSDK docs below. When I schedule the PHP call the UI is responsive temporarily until the call actually occurs.   http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/using_php

Comment: @fairwinds Is it possible to run background tasks in any of the TideSDK supported languages (Ruby, PHP, Python)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK its not possible. THe only way around this I found was to run the background process using the Ti.Process - which is basically running your script via CLI. However, I was only targeting one platform - osx.

Comment: I tried breaking up the curl_multi_exec() polling loop, returning to JS between polls. It didn't work because the PHP context was lost. I was unable to preserve variables between calls as if a brand new PHP stack launched.